# Most Important Elements inside a RSS/Atom feed

Tags: parsing, rss, element, atom-feed

We're building an "on-demand" feed parsing service (http://superfeedr.com) that developers can plug directly into their own applications.
Instead of building your own feed parsing module, and spending days in setting
it up and maintaining it, we do the "hard" work for you and our service sends you updates in real-time and standard ATOM format.

So far when we parse a feed, we only extract and send the entry *title*, *link*, *published date* and *summary*.

Which other elements would you expect to receive from our feed parser?

Comment: This kind of seems like it should be a poll. The elements that are important to a client will depend on what the client intends to do with the feed. A headline widget would be happy with what you're providing, while a podcast downloader would want enclosures, and a thumbnail viewer would want the various  MediaRSS extensions. BTW: I think you'll find that a lot of feeds lack summaries on their entries if they already have content elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Author's name.